# PyCharm Not Launching After macOS Update to Sonoma 14.0

Tags: python, macos, pycharm

I am encountering issues with PyCharm following the latest macOS Sonoma 14.0 update. Here are the problems I'm facing:

- PyCharm is not appearing in Spotlight Search.
- When I attempt to run PyCharm from the JetBrains Toolbox, it doesn't open.
- When running from iTerm using `pycharm .` it returns the following error:

```bash
The application /Users/user_name/Applications/PyCharm Professional Edition.app/Contents/MacOS/pycharm 
cannot be opened for an unexpected reason, error=Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 
"The file “pycharm” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." 
UserInfo={NSURL=file:///Users/user_name/Applications/PyCharm%20Professional%20Edition.app/Contents/MacOS/pycharm, 
NSFilePath=/Users/user_name/Applications/PyCharm Professional Edition.app/Contents/MacOS/pycharm, 
NSUnderlyingError=0x6000029e8780 
{Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstalling PyCharm fixes the issue.